# Playing around with shortcuts and window sizes with awesome WM

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, awesome

I've been trying awesome WM for a few months now and i am really enjoying it.
I am now playing around with the `rc.lua` file, and I'm searching for a way to do two things.

1. With the shortcut `mod4+Enter` (by default) you create a new terminal. In *magnified mode* (all floating) the term pops up quite small. I would like to be able to set the default size of a new term, BUT ONLY when it pops up (not when restarting awesome or anything else..)
   I've tried to set a rule for that:

   ```
   awful.rules.rules = {
       (...)
       { rule = { class = "URxvt" }, properties = { width = 900, height = 900 } }
       (...)
   }
   ```

   But when i restart awesome it messes up everything :/
   Any Idea on how to set a "only-when-pop-up" parameter for that?
2. I wand to be able to to something like `mod4 + doubleclick` on a window to maximize the size of a window (like the maximize button on any window in gnome)
   Any idea on how I could do that?

Comment: I realized afterwards that for 1. it was a setting from the terminal itself and it has nothing to do with awesome.
With URxvt I just had to use the geometry keyword:
`URxvt*geometry: 90x50` in **.Xdefaults**
Still searching an answer for 2. though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging:

1. With URxvt I just had to use the geometry keyword: `URxvt*geometry: 90x50` in **.Xdefaults**
2. Actually there already is a shortcut for maximizing a window and it is `mod4+m`. The double click event is not yet implemented in awesome (see [this topic](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.window-managers.awesome/7262), and there is a feature request in the bug tracker)